# Retrieve a list of all GET params?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, get, cdi

Is there an easy way to quickly get a list of all the GET parameters in the URL using CDI injection?

What I am looking for is something like:

```
@Inject
Map<String, String> allGetParams;
```

Comment: What I have, is a bunch of facelets using many GET parameters to show the right data. Now, on every page I have a choice of language, meaning every information is provided in multiple languages. So I want to keep all the parameters, but change the language parameter. Therefore I need the list of all GET params, to walk through them in a loop and change the language param. I would not say this to be a rare case, as every CMS with multiple languages should have a functionality that comes back on that. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: No, there is no bean that directly provides this.  You'll need to create your own producer method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like it has been said, you don't have it out of the box, but you can produce it like that in CDI 1.1+

```
public class MyProducer {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    Map<String,String[]> produceParamMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameterMap();
    }

}
```

in CDI 1.0 you'll have to use [Apache Deltaspike servlet module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/servlet.html) and write nearly the same

```
public class MyProducer {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    Map<String,String[]> produceParamMap(@Deltaspike HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameterMap();
    }

}
```

**EDIT : more details**

A producer (declared with `@Produces` annotation) is a way to declare a bean in CDI. Such a bean can be injected like any others. Here it'll be:

```
@Inject
Map<String,String[]> params;
```

So you don't call a producer method, it's the CDI container that uses it to instantiate a bean.

When you declare a producer method with parameters, the container will look for beans matching these parameter in order to call the method. Existence of these beans is check at boot time and they don't exist an exception is thrown (like any injection point with unsatisfied bean).

Here, in both case the bean of type HttpServletRequest is provided for you by CDI implementation (CDI 1.1+) or Deltaspike framework (CDI 1.0).

Comment: Wow! full example right away! Thanks a lot! Question: How would I call it? Where would I get the `HttpServletRequest` from?

Comment: @Socrates I added clarification about producers and their uses. I think you should take a moment to read CDI specification: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html or if don't feel like doing it the Weld documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-2.2/en-US/html/

Comment: Will do! Anyway, thank you very much! You already helped me a lot! And thanks as well for the links!